# Why java.util.BitSet does not implement java.util.Set

Tags: java, set, bitset

Why [`java.util.BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) does not implement [`java.util.Set<Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) interface. Especially when it can easily do so. Also BitSet is used to maintain if an integer was "switched on or not", Set also does exactly the same. So `BitSet` is a `Set<Integer>`. Referring to some comments saying that

> Now take a look at the methods of BitSet. The purpose of the class is to perform logical operations on a collection of bits that are in a certain order.

I would still say that `BitSet` is a `Set<Integer>` which also provides additional set of operations.

Comment: @f1sh I'm sure I've been to eating establishments where that would be debatable.

Comment: @djaqeel you didnt make AndyTurner's comment irrelevant, but mine. At least the second part of it. But now you just told everyone you edited your question, making it relevant again, yay! The first part of my comment is still my final answer.

Comment: BitSet is a vector of bits, while Set is a generic collection of non-duplicate objects. The statement "they behave differently and serve totally different purposes." from the above hotdog comment summarizes it perfectly well.

Comment: @djaqeel I think for performance reasons. They don't want people use this implementation (which is basically an optimization) through a generic interface, it would ruin the benefits of using it. One could write a wrapper around it if necessary.

Comment: for comment saying "vector of bit" vs "set" are different thing so `BitSet `should not implement `Set`, now we have `EnumSet` which is essentially doing the same thing as `BitSet` but it still implements `Set`...

Comment: One of the reason I can think of is `BitSet` is just too handicapped to be a `Set<Integer>`.  Provided an `Set<Integer>`, I am expecting either it is a mutable `Set` that I can add/remove etc, or it is an immutable `Set` that prohibit modification.  However `BitSet` only allow certain range of int to be used in modification, and such restriction is neither conventional, nor is understandable when it is used as `Set<Integer>`.  That may be one reason not to implement `Set<Integer>` as to avoid such kind of confusion and to avoid people treating `BitSet` as one proper impl of `Set`

Answer (score 0):

Since the comments don't make it obvious enough:

You say "BitSet is effectively an efficient set. BitSet is a Set" - no it is not. A `Set` is a collection which contains no duplicate elements.

Now imagine a `Set<Bit>`. Since a bit can only be 1 or 0, that will be a pretty boring set of a maximum size of 2.

Now take a look at [the methods of `BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html). The purpose of the class is to perform logical operations on a collection of bits that are in a certain order. That has nothing to do with a `Set`.

Comment: I think OP means `Set<Integer>`, which perfectly makes sense. The only con is that it could only handle a range of integers, not all of them. And those bitwise `or` and `and` logical operations would correspond to union and intersection.

Comment: @TamasHegedus where does this question have anything to do with a ``Set<Integer>``? OP's question is pretty straighforward.

Comment: The question itself is a bit low of quality sure, and would need some explanation, but for me, it is clearly about `Set<Integer>`.

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.BitSet` is in the JDK since version 1.0, `java.util.Set`entered the stage with JDK 1.2. So `BitSet` cannot implement `Set`.

If you need a `Set<>` implementation backed by a `BitSet`, that does not seem to hard to implement using a backing `BitSet`.

Comment: Also, an [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) is an implementation of `Set` that yields these benefits of a bit set: (a) being compact in memory and (b) very fast in execution. Represented internally as bit vectors.

Comment: `Hashtable`/`Stack`/`Vector` are in JDK since v 1.0, but they can still update to implement `Map` and `List` at 1.2.  Therefore this is not a valid reason.